# Validation of input field with icon send error message all together

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input-field

why all error message come together , i don't understand .
[image]

i need like this ..
[image]

ok , i can do this . here is my demo code .

```js
 $('#contact-form').validate({
    rules: {
        fullname: {
            minlength: 4,
            required: true
        },
        username: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password: {
            minlength: 6,
            required: true
        },
        confirm_password: {
            minlength: 6,
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#password"
        },
        mobile: {
            minlength: 11,
            maxlength: 11,
            required: true,
            number: true
        },
        conditions: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        var id_attr = "#" + $(element).attr("id") + "1";
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        var id_attr = "#" + $(element).attr("id") + "1";
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    },

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    }
});
```

```css
 label.error {
            float: right!important;
        }
        
        .controls .error {
            color: red!important;
        }
        
        .controls .valid {
            color: green!important;
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AGD Tracking</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- for checking validation -->

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">


            <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" id="contact-form">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                            <input type="text" id="fullname inputSuccess2" name="fullname" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>
                <br>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                            <input type="email" name="username" id="username-reg" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email address">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Your password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="repass" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm your Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                            <input type="text" name="mobile" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Number">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                 <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                       <button type="submit" id="emailSubmit" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-success btn-block" title="Submit"> Submit </button>
                        <br>
                        <input id="terms-and-conditions" type="checkbox" data-validation-required-message="You must agree to the terms and conditions" name="terms-and-conditions"> I agree to the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
                        <p class="help-block" style="display:none;"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
               

            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>

    </div>
```

But my problem is , when i add a submit button and and want that my full form validate then submit button will be enable otherwise from first it should be disable . 
i can also do that by this way :

```
$('#contact-form').on('keyup blur', function () {
    if ($('#contact-form').valid()) {
        if ($('#terms-and-conditions').click()) {
            $('button#emailSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('button#emailSubmit').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
});
```

but problem is after adding this , all error message come together . see :

```js
      $('#contact-form').validate({
    rules: {
        fullname: {
            minlength: 4,
            required: true
        },
        username: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password: {
            minlength: 6,
            required: true
        },
        confirm_password: {
            minlength: 6,
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#password"
        },
        mobile: {
            minlength: 11,
            maxlength: 11,
            required: true,
            number: true
        },
        conditions: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        var id_attr = "#" + $(element).attr("id") + "1";
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        var id_attr = "#" + $(element).attr("id") + "1";
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    },

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    }
});

$('#contact-form').on('keyup blur', function () {
    if ($('#contact-form').valid()) {
        if ($('#terms-and-conditions').click()) {
            $('button#emailSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('button#emailSubmit').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
});
```

```css
   label.error {
            float: right!important;
        }
        
        .controls .error {
            color: red!important;
        }
        
        .controls .valid {
            color: green!important;
        }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- for checking validation -->

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

            <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" id="contact-form">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                            <input type="text" id="fullname inputSuccess2" name="fullname" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>
                <br>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                            <input type="email" name="username" id="username-reg" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email address">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Your password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="repass" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm your Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                            <input type="text" name="mobile" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Number">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                 <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                       <button type="submit" id="emailSubmit" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-success btn-block" title="Submit"> Submit </button>
                        <br>
                        <input id="terms-and-conditions" type="checkbox" data-validation-required-message="You must agree to the terms and conditions" name="terms-and-conditions"> I agree to the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
                        <p class="help-block" style="display:none;"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
               

            </form>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle link ?

Comment: There are so many code to read. Can you get rid of some unnecessary code?

Comment: The validation is added to the form on keyup, that seems to be the reason for all inputs getting validated.

Comment: but why all error message come together ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are looking for this behavior:

Check if the current element is focused in the `highlight` and `errorPlacement` function so that only current focused element shows error.

```
highlight: function (element) {
    var id_attr = "#" + $(element).attr("id") + "1";
    if($(element).is(":focus")){
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    }
},

errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if($(element).is(":focus")) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yozn1kbb/1/

Comment: no , i need that , when i click on any input field for writting , only that will give me error message , other field should be normal .